# Getting overflow when I divide in assembly language

Tags: assembly, overflow, x86-16

I'm doing a code that add 2 numbers of 4 digits in assembly language (intel 8086). At some point in the code, I want to divide AX by BX register (using div BX), for example AX=2AB3 (10931 in decimal) and BX=2710 (10000 in decimal).

Normally, as result I should have AX=1 (quotient) and DX=3A3 (remainder), the problem is that the emulator show me the overflow message.

Here is the code :

```html
DATA SEGMENT

MSG1 DB 0DH,0AH, "first number  : $" ,0DH
MSG2 DB 0DH,0AH, "second number  : $" ,0DH
RST  DB 0DH,0AH, "result  : $" ,0DH

DATA ENDS
PILE SEGMENT PARA STACK
    DB 128 DUP (?)
PILE ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA,SS:PILE

DEBUT:   
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax

mov dx,offset MSG1     ; first msg
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ah,1     ; multipling first number by 1000 and store it
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,1000
mul bx
push ax

mov ah,1         ; multipling second number by 100 and store it
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,100
mul bx
push ax

mov ah,1        ; multipling third number by 10 and store it
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,10
mul bx
push ax
         
mov ah,1            ; last number
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
push ax


mov dx,offset MSG2    ;same thing for the second 4 digits number
mov ah,9
int 21h

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,1000
mul bx
push ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,100
mul bx
push ax

mov ah,1
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
mov bx,10
mul bx
push ax
         
mov ah,1         
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov ah,0
push ax
       ;-------------------------------
       ;here I'm doing the addition to all the stored numbers to have the result number
       ;in the DX register
pop dx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
pop bx
add dx,bx
push dx   ; I've stored the result number because I'm going to use the DX register to show the
          ; third message

mov dx,offset RST
mov ah,9
int 21h

pop dx   ;restore the result number
mov ax,dx
mov bx,10000   
div bx     ;I'm dividing the result number by 10000 to have the first number of the result number
           ;in AX register ( quotient) , the error message show up here
push dx    
push ax

pop dx
add dl,30h
mov ah,2
int 21h

pop ax
mov bx,1000 ;deviding by 1000 to have the second number
div bx     ;same error
push dx
push ax
pop dx
add dl,30h
mov ah,2
int 21h

pop ax
mov bx,100
div bx
push dx
push ax
pop dx
add dl,30h
mov ah,2
int 21h

pop ax
mov bx,10
div bx
push dx
push ax
pop dx
add dl,30h
mov ah,2
int 21h

pop dx

add dl,30h
mov ah,2
int 21h
```

Comment: May we see the code you're working on, or a relevant part of it?

Comment: Did you consult an instruction set reference? Did you see that the dividend is in `DX:AX`? Have you set up `DX` properly? Why didn't you show your code? Have you looked at the gazillion duplicates on SO?

Comment: (Your English seems fine to me, and we prefer questions here not to contain [apologies about language](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=sorry%20for%20my%20English) - it's just another thing to edit out).

Comment: I've added the code that I use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this change:

```
pop dx            ;restore the result number
mov ax,dx
xor dx,dx         ;; added this line to clear dx
mov bx,10000   
div bx
```

or it could be:

```
pop ax            ;; restore the result into ax
xor dx,dx         ;; added this line to clear dx
mov bx,10000   
div bx
```

Comment: I've tried the first thing and it did work ! Could you please explain to me why it doesn't work without your solution ?

Comment: @OmarAsrih the divide instruction divides the 32 bit value in dx:ax by the value in bx (in this case) producing a 16 bit quotient in ax, and a 16 bit remainder in dx. If dx is not zeroed before the divide instruction, you can get overflow, and in this case, dx needs to be zeroed to get the correct answer.